# rails link_to in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model named `event`, with the attribute: `after_create: post`.
In the `Post` method, I create a post and want in the `post.text` a link to `self.name`.

I want the event posted with a link, but I'm new to rails and I dont know how to do this.

```
    post.text = "<%=#{link_to self.name, event_path(event: self.uid)}%>"
```

I have already tried already with:

- link_to
- a-tag
- something like #{self.name}

Comment: Why do you want to store a link in `post.text`? You can always generate it from post's attributes (`name` and `uid`) wherever needed.

Comment: How does it works? Im sorry, but im quite new to rails..   edit: i want that the Event is previewed in the post and the Name of the Event links to the event itself

Comment: Oh, just sayin. Post is a model too

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the same:

```
   post.text = "a href='url'>text</a>
```

in the 'event.rb'.
Then go to the View, and add ".html_safe" to 'post.text'

That means for example:
show.html.erb

```
  <%= post.text.html_safe %>
```

--> its a link to the title